# Check if the WrapPanel is overflowed?

Tags: windows-phone-7, wrappanel

I'm currently doing some pagination things. I would like to know if I can check whether the TextBlock inside of the wrappanel is overflowed or not? By the way I would like to ask if you know something about pagination please give me some tuts. What I'm doing is split a big sized string to pages and display them to the phone screen. Thanks.

```
Microsoft.Phone.Controls.WrapPanel wrapPanel = new   Microsoft.Phone.Controls.WrapPanel();
wrapPanel.Width = calculatedWidth;
wrapPanel.Height = calculatedHeight;
wrapPanel.Margin = new Thickness(pageFormat.leftMargin,pageFormat.topMargin,pageFormat.rightMargin,pageFormat.bottomMargin);

TextBlock tbl = new TextBlock();
tbl.Text = " Some text here ... ";

wrapPanel.Children.Add(tbl);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Mango SDK, there is a property call [TextTrimming](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textblock.texttrimming%28v=vs.95%29.aspx).

So this xaml

```
<TextBlock Text="aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa" TextTrimming="WordEllipsis" Width="200" />
```

will produce somehting like *"aaaaaaa....."*

So for your code you just do it like:

`Tb1.TextWrapping=TextWrapping.WordEllipsis`

**EDIT**
There is a property called Wrap which u can set both in xaml and c#.
`<TextBlock text={Binding Text} TextWarapping="Wrap" />`

or in c# as

`MyTextBlock.TextWrapping=TextWrapping.wrap;`

Comment: I'm sorry but you've misunderstood my idea. I want to wrap text in a textblock control till it exceeding the fixed sizes(width and height). I'm not going to trim text here.